# How to read email using python and smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib, yandex

Found a lot of examples how to send mail, but how can I read inbox? For example yandex.

```
import smtplib as smtp

email = "me@example.com"
password = "password"

server = smtp.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.com')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo(email)
server.login(email, password)
server.auth_plain()
# server.get_and_print_your_inbox_magic_method()
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [SMTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) is for sending mails. If you want to look at your inbox - aka receive mails - you need to use [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) or [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol).

But just like [`smtplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html), Python also has [`imaplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) for IMAP and [`poplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/poplib.html) for POP3.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, you need:

- **SMTP** server for sending emails
- **IMAP** for reading emails
- **POP3** for reading emails

IMAP is more powerful than POP3; in general, you probably want to use IMAP. POP3 deletes the emails after they have been read, unlike IMAP.

---

For SMTP you can use Python's `smtplib`, for IMAP you can use `imaplib` and for POP3 you can use `poplib` (all from standard library). However, they are all pretty low-level.

I have created more abstract alternatives to make things easy for everyone:

- [Red Mail](https://red-mail.readthedocs.io/) for sending emails (SMTP)
- [Red Box](https://red-box.readthedocs.io/) for reading emails (IMAP)

Here is an example of Red Mail:

```
from redmail import EmailSender

# Configure sender
email = EmailSender(host="smtp.example.com", port=587)

# Send an email
email.send(
    subject="An example email",
    sender="me@example.com",
    receivers=['you@example.com'],
    text="Hello!",
    html="<h1>Hello!</h1>"
)
```

And an example of Red Box:

```
from redbox import EmailBox
from redbox.query import UNSEEN, SUBJECT

# Configure email box    
box = EmailBox(host="imap.example.com", port=993)

# Select email folder
inbox = box['INBOX']

for msg in inbox.search(UNSEEN & SUBJECT("An example email")):
    # Process the message
    print(msg.subject)
    print(msg.from_)

    # Mark the message as read
    msg.read()
```

You can pip install the libraries:

```
pip install redmail redbox
```

---

#### Relevant links

Red Box:

- [Source code](https://github.com/Miksus/red-box)
- [Documentation](https://red-box.readthedocs.io/)

Red Mail:

- [Source code](https://github.com/Miksus/red-mail)
- [Documentation](https://red-mail.readthedocs.io/)